# SwiftUI Error No ObservableObject of type GlobalEnvironment found

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I thought I had everything set up correctly, but my app is crashing...in SceneDelegate, I have this code:

```
// Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = CalculatorView().environmentObject(GlobalEnvironment())

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and in my CalculatorView struct I have:

```
@EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnvironment

var body: some View {

                HStack() {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(env.outputToScreen)
```

and I have a class called "GlobalEnvironment" inheriting from ObservableObject, with @Published properties that are set like this:

```
class GlobalEnvironment: ObservableObject {

    @Published var textOutputToScreen: String = "Enter Name"
```

However, when my CalculatorView struct changes the value of textOutputToScreen, the whole thing crashes...all the help I found said to set the GlobalEnvironment in SceneDelegate, but I've already done that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a button in your code. So, I made this program based on what you showed me and it works.

SceneDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var env = GlobalEnvironment()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = CalculatorView().environmentObject(env)

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Then the CalculatorView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalculatorView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnvironment
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(env.textOutputToScreen)
        }
    }
}
```

And then the GlobalEnvironment:

```
import SwiftUI

class GlobalEnvironment: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textOutputToScreen = "Enter Name"
}
```

This gives me this result, which is what the code should produce.
[image]

Comment: safe to assume the missing period on `let contentView = CalculatorView()environmentObject(env)` is a typo?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes. Typo from my side. I can't test your code, so I had to look in my old tryouts how this was done. By adjusting the names, I accidentally deleted the period. I changed it.

Comment: I actually asked the wrong question, this works but doesn't quite solve the problem I'm having. Going to open another question up soon to help clarify (once i figure out how to ask it)